# Web-based document sharing for small organizations

Tags: documentation, salesforce

In the past I have used nexo.com to share documents with sales, marketing, PR, and technical people for a small startup. But I wonder if there is a better solution to allow different types of geo-graphically dispersed workers to get to a variety of uploaded documents. I don't want to have to build or host this myself, and free or cheap is always nice.

I read about Confluence, but it seems to be way more than what I need. I simply want access-controlled folders in the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this myself just yet, but I've heard great things about it [google docs](http://docs.google.com)

Answer (score 2):

We use [s3fm](http://www.s3fm.com/) for that. It's a free solution but requires an Amazon S3 account. Since we have one for our hosting needs that was an obvious choice. But given Amazon S3 bottom pricing I think it might make sense to consider open one just for that.

Answer (score 1):

Love Dropbox!!!  I haven't used it for setting up a lot of group access, though.

Sounds like [Google Sites](http://www.google.com/sites/help/intl/en/overview.html) would help you a lot.  You can set up a network of distinct Web sites -- one for sales, another for marketing, another for PR -- and upload your files to them.  You can determine who has access to each site as well as each page of content.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else checks this Q:
Wound up using filesanywhere.com - has the exact features I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We use a combination of:

- Backpack
- SVN
- JungleDisk

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Dropbox](https://www.getdropbox.com/home).

Access control is somewhat limited, but it's been working out very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm in the middle of writing such an application for a client. The best thing I can recommend is taking an existing web based file manager and adding in the permission feature.

Answer (score 0):

With a big freaking huge disclaimer that I work on this as my day job:

If you're looking for feedback on those documents [Backboard](http://www.getbackboard.com) gives you web-based viewing and collaboration with no software required.

Answer (score 0):

there is a product called docpro.this allows you to set up various security levels,routing methods etc.Its a web based one you can use for geographically dispersed team members across the globe.But its not free,But cheap i think.
Check this link

http://www.omnexsystems.com/Faq/documentpro.html